# invalid syntax on python

Tags: python, syntax-error

booth with my raspi and im getting a anoyying syntax

```
`#!/usr/bin/python

print 'ACTIVATED'

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO library

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN) ## Setup GPIO Pin 40 to OUT
GPIO.input(40) ## Turn on GPIO pin 40
for x in xrange(10):
if(GPIO.input(40) == 100GPIO.input(40)  
GPIO.input(40) ## Turn on GPIO pin 40
      print ('CHEESE')
```

the part in bold above is the problem, this is the syntax error

```
File "./gid.py", line 11
if(GPIO.input(40) == 100GPIO.input(40) 
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

im a coding newbie

Comment: You're missing a `)` on that line, and the syntax looks strange anyway. Are you trying to check if it's equal to 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few problems.  The comment doesn't make sense.  Do you want pin 40 to be an input or an output?

```
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN) ## Setup GPIO Pin 40 to OUT
```

If you actually want it to be an output, it should probably be:

```
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO Pin 40 to OUT
```

This next line doesn't turn on pin 40.  It reads pin 40 and returns 0 or 1.  That return value is lost if you don't assign it to a variable.

```
GPIO.input(40) ## Turn on GPIO pin 40
```

What you probably want is:

```
GPIO.output(40,1) ## Turn on GPIO pin 40
```

The next lines are also a mess:

```
if(GPIO.input(40) == 100GPIO.input(40)  
GPIO.input(40) ## Turn on GPIO pin 40
      print ('CHEESE')
```

Not sure what you actually want, but something that could work is:

```
if GPIO.input(40) == 1:  # Read what is currently being output
    GPIO.output(40,0)    #   and turn it off if it is on, perhaps?
```

Note that Python `if` statements end in a colon and don't require parentheses around the comparison.

You might check out:  http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Examples/

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a colon after `if`, and I think you mean `if input is 100`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print('ACTIVATED')

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO library

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN) ## Setup GPIO Pin 40 to OUT
GPIO.input(40) ## Turn on GPIO pin 40

for x in xrange(10):
  if GPIO.input(40) == 100: # you're missing a colon in your if statement
    GPIO.input(40)
    GPIO.input(40) ## Turn on GPIO pin 40
    print('CHEESE')
```

Comment: i tried your code and it said                                       ./gid.py: 1: ./gid.py: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: Do you use Python3.x or Python2.x, plz?

Comment: no idea im using my dads older computer for a science project

Comment: ...Well, can you post in which line you get the error info?

Comment: ./gid.py: 1: ./gid.py: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: I don't know how to deal it , have you try `python gid.py`? or try the update code?

Comment: but now when i add if (line11) it says that 40 is a invalid syntax